# How to pass JTW token (or any other variable) from parent to children resolver with Aws AppSync

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, vtl

**I'm trying to pass a JWT token to my nested queries in AppSync** to check that the user has the right to ask for such data.

The problem is that AppSync **doesn't let me forward the JWT token from my parent queries to any child resolver**.

Example :

```
mutation test {
emailSignIn(input: {email: "0@gmail.com", password: "XYZ"}) {
token
currentUser {
  id
  profilePicture {
    uuid
  }
  ... on Client {
    lastName
    pleadingList{
      id
      pleadingFiles {
        uuid
      }
      pleadingParticipantSlots {
        id
        participant {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
}
}
```

**Here `profilePicture`, `pleadingList`, `pleadingFiles`, `pleadingParticipantSlots`, `participant` are subqueries** and I want to be able to identify who is doing each subqueries not only the main/parent query

Is there any solution?

What I already tried:

- [AWS AppSync: pass arguments from parent resolver to children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52512011/aws-appsync-pass-arguments-from-parent-resolver-to-children)

The issue is that when I add dynamically the token to the main result, it doesn't always work (in a sense that if what I get back from my query is an array of Item, and a subquery is a launch for each item, then I don't have access to the token in each subrequest because the `$ctx.source` will only be the item without the token.

- I also tried pipeline to add the JWT token to `ctx.stash` but it's even worst because the `ctx.stash` (and the `ctx.args`) get cleared before any subrequest

So what I would like is a way to pass a variable to all my child resolver or a way to keep my header from parent request to nested query.

The only way I make it work (and it's very ugly and I don't want to do that ;) ) is to add in the front-end the token as query and subquery parameter each time ...

like:

```
mutation test {
emailSignIn(input: {email: "0@gmail.com", password: "XYZ"}) {
token
currentUser {
  id
  profilePicture(token: "blablabla") {
    uuid
  }
  ... on Client {
    lastName
    pleadingList(token: "blablabla") {
      id
      pleadingFiles(token: "blablabla") {
        uuid
      }
      pleadingParticipantSlots {
        id
        participant(token: "blablabla") {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
}
}
```

I'm kind of lost and don't find anything relevant in AWS AppSync docs.
Is there any way? Or am I thinking it wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, AppSync does not support passing JWT tokens from the parent to child resolver. The workaround you have mentioned might be one of the current options.